# VB.NET - I'm curious, why does the return from "Right" not work as a string?

Tags: vb.net

If I have a string like input = "AA["

```
If Right(input, 1) = "[" Then Do stuff
```

The If statement returns false, even if I try converting things around to chars, etc etc. But if I do this is returns true:

```
Dim temp As String = Right(input, 1)
If temp = "[" Then Do Stuff
```

I like knowing little semantics like this, any idea why it comes out this way?

Comment: Strangely, I did some more coding and then came back to this, and it now works. It couldn't have been something else I changed, because I tried just printing out "AAAAAAA" for Do Stuff, and the "AAAAAAA" would only print with the If temp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen weird behavior like that when debugging.

In fact, today I had something simlar

```
 Dim records As Integer
 records = If(o.dr Is Nothing, o.ADO.rs.RecordCount, o.ADO.DS.Tables("tbl").Rows.Count)
```

That should work, using the rs.RecordCount when dr is nothing, otherwise using the Rows.Count.  It didn't, records was ending up as zero.  Rewrote it as a full if then/else block and it works.

It's never my first thought that the compiler/debugger/ide is messing things up, but you should keep it in the back of your mind for consideration: the programmers that wrote those programs are just as human and fallible as you or me.

Answer (score 2):

Or don't use Right at all since this is .Net

```
    Dim s As String = "AAAAAAA]"
    If s.Substring(s.Length - 1, 1) = "]" Then
        Stop
    End If
    'or
    If s(s.Length - 1) = "]" Then
        Stop
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't. Are you sure you didn't have a typo? The result of RIGHT is a string, and if the input was truly "AA[" the IF will have passed.

I've never had VB act wonky on something like this.

Comment: I was sure it was a typo too, but I even tried directly copying it (and just putting in temp in place of the Right statement) and yet it still didn't work

Comment: FYI, RIGHT() function is part of the vb compatibility lib.  For framework compatibility with other languages (for potential conversion purposes) you should use:  If input.EndsWith("[") Then Do Stuff

Answer (score 0):

If the code appears in a form, then the .Right property of the form overrides the string manipulation function. You need to specify the parent namespace - e.g. VisualBasic.Right - to ensure that you get the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have some kind of strange overload confusion occuring here.

You are specifiing "Right" (which could be calling a local "Right" function).
The function your implying is "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right" in most of my code ends up being "Strings.Right" due to the global import.

I would try changing you code to the below and see if it still happens, in order to rule out some overload/scope confusion. (and/or the reduced "Strings.Right")

```
If Micosoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right(input, 1) = "[" Then Do stuff
```